# Uber api access_token goes bad and can not be refreshed

Tags: oauth-2.0, uber-api

It is mentioned in oauth documentation at https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/ that access token remains valid for 30 days. But I have started getting invalid credential error within a week. The exact error I am getting is:-

```
{"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"}
```

Trying refresh token after this error gives invalid grant error whereas 'refresh_token' is valid grant type.

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

Anyone facing similar issues?

Comment: yes. I Got Access token expired in one day. 
Are you still facing this problem?

Comment: I now get the same `{"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"}` even though I keep refreshing my access token.

Answer (score 3):

If your client credentials are used to get another access token, that will invalidate former access tokens associated with that user.

When an access token expires, you must obtain a new access token. Use the refresh token to get a new access token without prompting a user to login and grant permission again. The refresh token itself is not a valid token to access API endpoints - it is just a code you keep to exchange for a new access token when yours expires. This is described in **Step Five: Refreshing Tokens** in [Uber's Authentication Guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication).